# How to add null valued rows in the end after finding the avg()

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose we have a table with 3 columns student_id, student_name and marks which stores marks of each student for all subject for all exams. Some students did not attend any exam so their marks are represented as NULL.

We want to find the avg marks of each student and order it in descending order. And in the end, we also need to include the students who did not attend any exams and for the column avg(marks) for these students, we should put NULL.

For example:
Output should be

[image]

i.e., we should include the students in the end have all their marks as NULL.

Comment: You must use a table which contains all `student_id` values (including those who're absent in marks table). Join marks table to students list table and get the list which you need.

Comment: please provide us query you have trying for this.

Comment: What is your MySQL Version? Do you have any `subject` column? or only 3 columns and you are finding average based on 'student_id' ?

Comment: Average is nonsensical in the context as presently described. Each student could have only one entry UNLESS student name ISN'T a column in this table, AND subject IS!!!!!

Comment: You want AVERAGE mark for a student. This means that more than one record for a separate `student_id` value may exist. Imagine that for some `student_id` there exists 3 records with the marks `60`, `90` and `NULL`. What average do you want for such student? `75`? `50`? `NULL`? something else (what and why)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try following query.

```
select student_id, avg(marks)
from student
group by student_id
order by avg(marks) desc
```

Comment: This doesn't give the student_names with null values in the end.

Comment: @SharadSharma . . . It doesn't give student names because they are not in your the data described in your question.  It should put `NULL` values at the end, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
select student_id, avg(marks) from tbStudent group by student_id order by avg(marks) desc
```

Comment: Student name is not part of the requested output